# Android visibility issue with checkbox

Tags: android, layout, checkbox, view, visibility

I´m using a checkbox in my code that when its checked it makes a textview and a editText visibles, but if I uncheck de checkbox they continue being visible instead of dissapear.

Here is the code:

```
final CheckBox save = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {



                // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

                    nameText.setVisibility(1);
                    editName.setVisibility(1);

                } else {

                    nameText.setVisibility(0);
                    editName.setVisibility(0);

                }
            }
        });
```

And part of the xml which is inside an Relative Layout:

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below = "@+id/linearLayout2">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/name" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/name" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>    


    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What should i do to make the textView and EditText dissapear when i uncheck the checkbox?

Thank you!

Comment: I agree with Roflcoptr but recently I have been experimenting with a few related issues and found that if you did (for some crazy reason) want to use integer values they are not 0 and 1 but rather it is: 0 - visible 4 - invisible 8 - gone Not sure why these are multiples of 4.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `View.VISIBLE`, `View.INVISIBLE`, `View.GONE` to control visibility (instead of 0 & 1).

Answer (score 6):

Two things:

1. You should use [`setOnCheckedChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)), which will make your life easier.
2. You should use View.GONE and View.VISIBLE instead of integers for `setVisibility()`.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is in this part:

```
 // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

                    nameText.setVisibility(1);
                    editName.setVisibility(1);

                } else {

                    nameText.setVisibility(0);
                    editName.setVisibility(0);

                }
```

yout shouldn't use integer values, but instead use the constants provided by the view class

// Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

```
                nameText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                editName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                nameText.setVisibility(VIEW.INVISIBLE);
                editName.setVisibility(VIEW.INVISIBLE);

            }
```

instead of invisible you could also use GONE. then your invisible textedit doesn't need space in the layout

if you check the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) you will see that 1 isn't a valid parameter: